# Windows 7: What can I do with my disk to install Ubuntu 14.04 as second OS?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

Right now I have Windows 7 installed as main OS. When I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 as second OS, I see my disk space as one partition.

Here are my partitions:

[image: Disk partitions]

Is it possible to create new drive to install Ubuntu 14.04 on it without breaking current Windows 7?

Comment: Do you see something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/h7CXmhZ.png)?

Answer (score 2):

In green on the screenshot, you've got around 200 GB of free space.

You should be able to use this space to create an `ext3` partition along with a `swap` partition for Ubuntu to be installed.

The easiest way to do this is to startup a live Ubuntu from DVD or USB. When the live OS is loaded, use [GParted](http://gparted.org/) to prepare your drive. Then restart your computer and choose to install Ubuntu still from DVD or USB.

You will have to be careful on configuring properly the paritions to use at some step in the installation wizard.

Comment: When I'm doing that it show my hard drive as full disk with 931GB

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is **[dual boot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-booting)** Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

---

When you install Ubuntu, the grub boot loader is automatically installed. This allows you to choose whether you want to boot between Windows or Ubuntu/Linux.

**What to do:**
Run the Ubuntu installer as usual and when it comes to the part when you choose *Installation type*, select *Something else*:
[image: Choosing installation type in Ubuntu 12.04]
<sup>***Note***: Screenshot taken from Ubuntu 12.04</sup>

You should then see list of partitions in window like this:
[image: List of partitions]
<sup>***Note***: Screenshot taken from Ubuntu 12.04</sup>

Select which disk you want to install it on, select the free space
which you cleared/created. Then create a partition using *Add...* button, format it as a ext3 or ext4 and mount it as `/`. Click install and it will do its job and install on that partition not touching the windows partition.

---

When you boot your PC next time you should see something like this:
[image: This is the Grub boot loader]
*This is the grub boot loader*

You can use arrow keys to choose and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm, or wait a few seconds to load default OS.

<sup>**Note:** It is always handy to have windows installer ready in case something goes wrong. You can restore the normal boot loader this way (without loosing any files).</sup>